# Creating dynamic dropdown - Flutter Issue Items reads zero

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello I tried to create a dynamic dropdown with flutter. the request to end point returns the data successfully but the DropdownButtonFormField items array is reading zero. it is not getting the data at all. Please can any one help me?

Dropdown menu items variable:

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem> _anchorLists = List<DropdownMenuItem>();
  dynamic _selectedAnchor;


 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getAnchorsByProvider();
    
  }
```

The Function:

```
  _getAnchorsByProvider() async {
    try {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _anchorService = AnchorService();
      var result = await _anchorService
          .getAnchorsByProviderId(_prefs.getInt('providerOid'));
      var anchors = json.decode(result.body);

      anchors.forEach((anchor) {
        setState(() {
          _anchorLists.add(DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(anchor['acronym']),
            value: anchor['oid'],
          ));
        });
      });
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

The Dropdown

```
  SizedBox(height: 20),
      (_anchorLists.length > 0)? 
         DropdownButtonFormField(
           value: _selectedAnchor,
           items: _anchorLists,
           hint: const Text('Select your Anchor'),
            onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                 _selectedAnchor = value;
               });
           },
         )
      : Text('Loading'),
```

Result
[image]

Values of the json:

[image]

```
{
    "oid": 1,
    "acronym": "MAAN",
    "contactAddress": "Abuja",
    "idCardInstruction": null,
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your issue is in the conversion from json. Check the value of `anchors` and the structure of the json body. Please share those values here if you are still unable to resolve.

Comment: Please this are the values. Let me update the question with values.

Comment: This is definitely the issue. Are you expecting a single object containing 'oid', 'acronym', etc. or are you expecting a list of objects containing these values? You seem to be doing a little of both. You request a single object by `ProviderId` but try to process a list of objects.

Comment: Sorry I am expecting a single object containing 'oid', 'acronym', etc @Lee3

Comment: Great. And you wish to list every value in the object? Just those that are non-null? Or only specific ones? I will have an answer for you after your response.

Comment: ok only specific ones. the id and the name hence it is a dropdown @Lee3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are retrieving a json object (`Map`) and not a json list (`List`), `forEach` must iterate through `key` and `value` pairs, like so:

```
anchors.forEach((key, value) {
  _anchorLists.add(DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text(value.toString()),
    value: value.toString(),
  ));
});
```

I'm not sure of the specifics of your needs so tweak accordingly, but if you only wish to provide specific values, you can specify like so:

```
_anchorLists.addAll([anchors['acronym'], anchors['oid']]
    .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(value.toString()),
        value: value.toString(),
    )));
```

Comment: OK so this goes for list of objects right? @Lee3 anchors.forEach((key, value) {
  _anchorLists.add(DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text(value.toString()),
    value: value.toString(),
  ));
});

Comment: This will only go through the key value pairs. What you had will work if a list of objects is returned. But your `getAnchorsByProviderId` method will return only 1 object in the search. You will never have a list of objects.